# How to achieve parallax occlusion mapping using three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I know that by assigning texture to `normalMap` property of material we can achieve normal mapping using three.js. How do we achieve parallax occlusion mapping using three.js? Is there a direct implementation or we need to do some adjustments based on normal mapping? Thanks.

Comment: See the [three.js example](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_parallaxmap.html).

Comment: @WestLangley Thanks for your comment. I will check it out.